# PySide: QAbstractItemModel not talking to simple controls

Tags: pyqt, pyqt4, pyside

Using PySide, I am trying to connect several data controls to data from a file that I read from disc. So I made a data model, derived from QAbstractItemModel. Should be trivial, right? But one problem that has me beaten is connecting QLineEdit and QTextEdit controls to show and allow editing of the data in the model.

From examples such as the Simple Widget Mapper and the Combo Widget Mapper in the QT documentation, I believe I have to have a data model with one row, and a QWidgetMapper to connect the cells in that row to the edit controls.

Here is a very cut-down program that shows the problem. The data model in this example returns the three strings x1, x2 and x3. The strings are changed from e.g. "First (1)" to "First (2)" by calling Update, i.e. by clicking the "Next" button. That is to simulate new values being read from a file or wherever. The main window has a couple of QLineEdits and a QTextEdit, which the mapper should link to the model data. But the data don't show up in the edit controls.

To check the model, I added a QTableView. The data show up there alright, and update when "Next" is clicked, so it's not the data model. It's something between there and the edit controls. But I cannot see what I am not doing, that the widget mapper examples are doing.

What am I doing wrong?

Incidentally, going the other way doesn't work well either. If I add a setData() method to the model, and emit dataChanged, a change typed into the line edit gets to the Table. But even when that happens, the item disappears from the line edit. And after "Next" is clicked, this stops working for the QLineEdit and QTextEdit -- setData() no longer gets called. But if I edit in the table view, setData is still called.

Here is the example code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys
from PySide.QtCore import ( Qt, QAbstractItemModel,QModelIndex
                          )
from PySide.QtGui import ( QApplication, QMainWindow, QPushButton, QWidget,
                           QTextEdit, QLineEdit, QFormLayout, QTableView,
                           QDataWidgetMapper, 
                         )

##############################################################################
class TModel(QAbstractItemModel):
  """
  This model will have 1 row of 3 items

  There will be a slot that will change the items. If they are displayed
  in widgets, I want to see them update.
  """

  def __init__(self, parent=None):
    super(TModel, self).__init__(parent)

    self.counter = 0
    self.x1 = ""
    self.x2 = ""
    self.x3 = ""
    self.Update()

  def columnCount(self, index=QModelIndex()):
    return 3

  def rowCount(self, index=QModelIndex()):
    return 1

  def index(self, row, column, index=QModelIndex()):
    if not self.hasIndex(row, column, index):
      return QModelIndex()
    return self.createIndex(row, column)

  def parent(self, index):
    return QModelIndex()

  def hasChildren(self, index):
    return False

  def data(self, index, role=Qt.DisplayRole):
    if index.isValid():
      if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
        if index.column() == 0:
          return self.x1
        elif index.column() == 1:
          return self.x2
        elif index.column() == 2:
          return self.x3

    return None

  def headerData(self, section, orientation, role):
    if role != Qt.DisplayRole:
      return None

    if orientation == Qt.Horizontal:
      if section == 0:
        return "col 1"
      elif section == 1:
        return "col 2"
      elif section == 2:
        return "col 3"

  def Update(self):
    self.beginResetModel()
    self.x1 = "First (%d)"%self.counter
    self.x2 = "Second (%d)"%self.counter
    self.x3 = "Third (%d)"%self.counter
    self.counter += 1
    self.endResetModel()



##############################################################################
class TMainWindow(QMainWindow):
  """Main GUI object"""

  def __init__(self, parent=None):
    super(TMainWindow, self).__init__(parent)

    self.DataModel = TModel()

    self.Mapper = QDataWidgetMapper()
    self.Mapper.setSubmitPolicy(self.Mapper.AutoSubmit)
    self.Mapper.setModel(self.DataModel)

    self.FirstFieldEdit = QLineEdit()
    self.SecondFieldEdit = QLineEdit()
    self.ThirdFieldEdit = QTextEdit()

    self.Mapper.addMapping(self.FirstFieldEdit, 0)
    self.Mapper.addMapping(self.SecondFieldEdit, 1)
    self.Mapper.addMapping(self.ThirdFieldEdit, 2)
    self.Mapper.toFirst()

    self.UpdateButton = QPushButton("Next")
    self.UpdateButton.clicked.connect(self.DataModel.Update)

    formLayout = QFormLayout()
    formLayout.addRow("&First:",  self.FirstFieldEdit)
    formLayout.addRow("&Second:", self.SecondFieldEdit)
    formLayout.addRow("&Third:",  self.ThirdFieldEdit)
    formLayout.addRow("",         self.UpdateButton)

    self.testTable = QTableView()
    self.testTable.setModel(self.DataModel)
    formLayout.addRow("Table:", self.testTable)

    W = QWidget()
    W.setLayout(formLayout)
    self.setCentralWidget(W)



##############################################################################

if __name__ == "__main__":
  app = QApplication(sys.argv)
  MainWindow = TMainWindow()
  MainWindow.show()
  sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `QDataWidgetMapper` class is intended to allow displaying and editing records in a model. But your model doesn't return anything when data is requested for editing. So a simple fix would be:

```
    def data(self, index, role=Qt.DisplayRole):
        if index.isValid():
            if role == Qt.DisplayRole or role == Qt.EditRole:
                ...
```

**EDIT**:

From the Qt Docs:

> QDataWidgetMapper can be used to create data-aware widgets by mapping
>   them to **sections** of an item model. A section is a **column** of a model if
>   the orientation is horizontal (the default), otherwise a **row**. [emphasis added]

I would suggest you avoid trying to write a custom model (which is very far from trivial, except for the simplest of cases), and start by using a [QStandardItemModel](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstandarditemmodel.html).

Comment: That's part of it, thanks. It does allow the edit controls to show the data on startup. But they don't get updated when the model's data changes (click Next). Maybe Update() is wrong? When I added setData(), it stopped getting called after Update() was called (because Next was clicked). But I don't see what could be wrong with it?

Comment: @fpeelo. TBH, I have no idea what you're trying to achieve with that model.  For instance, how can it make sense for `rowCount` to always return `1`? A model should contain multiple records, with each row corresponding to one record. I think you need to read the [guidance on model subclassing](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/model-view-programming.html#model-subclassing-reference), or look at a properly worked out pyside/pyqt example.

Comment: I'm making a program to view (and eventually edit) an xml file. My problem is with attributes of the root node - there can only be one of each, hence one row. According to pages such as [this one](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qdatawidgetmapper.html) QDataWidgetMapper is the way to make data-aware widgets. I would love it if you could point me at a properly worked example; I searched before posting, but any examples that I found are for stepping through rows.  Or maybe QDataWidgetMapper is not the way to do what I am trying to do? Are data-aware widgets the wrong way to do this?

Comment: From the Qt Docs: "QDataWidgetMapper can be used to create data-aware widgets by mapping them to **sections** of an item model. A section is a **column** of a model if the orientation is horizontal (the default), otherwise a **row**." I would suggest you forget about trying to write a custom model (which is very far from trivial, except for the simplest of cases), and use a [QStandardItemModel](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstandarditemmodel.html).

Comment: Thanks, I think that will be my answer: Don't Use QAbstractItemModel. I did read those docs, and understood that I needed one column for each widget (IMO a column is still a column when there is only one row). Only question now is, how do I flag the answer?  I've clicked the comment, rather than the original answer, is that correct?

Comment: @fpeelo. I've added that comment to my answer. if you want to know how to accept answers, [see here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235).